# Paginating my blog doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I'm trying to make a paginating blog using PHP, HTML, and MySQL. I wrote the code but for some reason the webpage shows up blank. What's wrong with my code? Chrome's console returns a 500 internal server error.

```
<div id="article">

<?php
  include 'php/mysql_connect.php';
  if(empty($_GET)){
    $current_id = SELECT max(id) FROM posts;
  }
  else{
    $current_id = mysql_safe_string($_GET['id']);
  }

  $result = mysql_safe_query('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=%s LIMIT 1',$current_id);
  if(!mysql_num_rows($result)){
    echo '<h2>No Posts Found</h2>';
    exit;
  }

  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
  echo '<h2>'.$row['title'].'</h2>';
  echo '<div class="row">';
  echo '  <div class="group1 col-sm-6 col-md-6">';
  echo '    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#comments" class"collapsed">'.$row['num_comments'].' Comments </a>';
  echo '    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>'.date('F j<\s\up>S</\s\up>, Y', $row['date']);
  echo '  </div>';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '<br />';
  echo '<p class="lead">'.n12br($row['body']).'</p>';
  ?> 

  <div id="comments" class="collapse" >
    <div class="well">
      <h4>Leave a comment</h4>
      <?php echo '<form role="form" method="post" action="php/comment_add.php?id=($current_id)" class="clearfix">'; ?>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
          <label class="sr-only" for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name" required />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required />
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="content">Comment</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="content" placeholder="Comment" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 form-group text-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <br>

<?php 
  $result = mysql_safe_query('SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id=%s ORDER BY date ASC',$current_id);
  echo '  <ul id="comments" class="comments">';

  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo '    <li class="comment">';
  echo '      <div id="inline" ><h4 style="display:inline;">'.$row['name'].'</h1><sup><p style="display:inline; font-size:10px;">&nbsp; '.date('j-M-Y g:ia', $row['date']).'</p></sup></div>';
  echo '      <em>'.n12br($row['content']).'</em>';
  echo '    </li>';
  echo '  </ul>';
  }
?>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>

<nav>
  <ul class="pager">
<?php

    $newer_id = IFNULL(mysql_safe_query('SELECT min(id) FROM posts WHERE id > $current_id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1'),-1);
    $older_id = IFNULL (mysql_safe_query('SELECT max(id) FROM posts WHERE id < $current_id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1'),-1);

    if($newer_id != -1){
      echo '<li><a href="#">Newer</a></li>';
    }
    if ($older_id != -1){
      echo '<li><a href="#">Older</a></li>';
    }
?>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This is php/mysql_connect.php, which is supposed to prevent sql injection (i got this from a tutorial):

```
<?php
// mysql.php
function mysql_safe_string($value) {
    $value = trim($value);
    if(empty($value))           return 'NULL';
    elseif(is_numeric($value))  return $value;
    else                        return "'".mysql_real_escape_string($value)."'";
}

function mysql_safe_query($query) {
    $args = array_slice(func_get_args(),1);
    $args = array_map('mysql_safe_string',$args);
    return mysql_query(vsprintf($query,$args));
}

function redirect($uri) {
    header('location:'.$uri);
    exit;
}

mysql_connect('localhost','(username)','(password)');
mysql_select_db('(database)');
```

From the logs I locate the failure which is:

```
Syntax error, unexpected 'max' (T_STRING) on line 6 (if(empty($_GET)){$current_id = SELECT max(id) FROM posts})
```

Comment: If you are getting a `500` there should be a log somewhere. Posting the relevant parts of it would be a first step to make clear what error you are facing.

Comment: Syntax error, unexpected 'max' (T_STRING) on line 6 (if(empty($_GET)){$current_id = SELECT max(id) FROM posts})

Comment: You were using an old tutorial. `mysql_*` functions (known as `ext/mysql`) are deprecated and should not be used. Instead you should use [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Okay, so if I remove all the mysql_safe_string and mysql_safe_query, how would I use a PDO to make the $current_id variable safe?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(empty($_GET)){
    $current_id = SELECT max(id) FROM posts;
}
```

no quotes around the sql is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

As other pointed out (and it should be immediately clear by the syntax error you are facing), your `$current_id` query is not being quoted. A good beginning is to fix the first block as such:

```
if(empty($_GET)) {
    $current_id = "SELECT max(id) FROM posts;";
} else {
    $current_id = mysql_safe_string($_GET['id']);
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. Does it matter if they are single or double quotes?

Answer (score 0):

If your file is `myfile.html` and you don't have permission for embedded PHP it will not execute on the server.